# How can I import a val from the package object to ScalaWorksheet?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I have a package object

```
package com.test

package object data {
  val list = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
}
```

I want to use the `list` within my Scala Worksheet file `Demo.sc`:

```
import com.test.data._

list foreach println
```

But `IntelliJ Idea` says:

```
Error:(20, 2) not found: value list
list foreach println
^
```

Is it possible to do such thing in Idea? Maybe there is a flag in Settings or some another dirty hack?

Comment: Note that error given is for `data foreach println`, not `list foreach println`. Check that the code in the worksheet is actually as above. Do you have `Make project` checked?

Comment: Yes, I updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

You should check `Make project` checkbox in scala worksheet to get your project compiled. I just tested it, had very same error, until I compiled project.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely due to an error building your project in IntelliJ, rather than a scala code issue.

Running the code via the terminal:

```
$ scalac Demo.scala
$ scala
  scala> import com.test.data._
  # import com.test.data._
  scala> list foreach println
  1
  2
  3
  4
  5
  6
  7
  8
  9
  10
```

This suggests to me that your IntelliJ project is not correctly loading 'Demo.scala' to your classpath.

Answer (score -1):

Simply remove the `package` keyword before the `object data.

```
package com.test

object data {
  val list = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
}
```

In Demo.sc

```
import com.test.data._

list foreach println
```

Comment: I think it is an intellij IDE issue. When I try this on Eclipse IDE it  with `package object data` it complains `data is already defined as data object` and it works perfectly without the package keyword as mentioned above. So I think the downvote here is not fair.